# awk to multiple variable in for loop

Tags: awk

Would like to read 6th line (var=i), 9th line(var=j), 12th line (var=k) then output as first row
then increment by 10 lines ( i+10;j+10;k+10) and output as second row , and so on ...

Input.txt

```
MN
LIST

DETAILS
AAAA             BBBB           CCCC
123421751116849  119865688385     IDLE

DATE             TIME             DDDD
150203           161044           123-42-50300-14481

EEEE
111394052866500

DETAILS
AAAA             BBBB           CCCC
123421825027128  119698116932     IDLE

DATE             TIME             DDDD
150204           183507           123-42-3200-10793

EEEE
352708042150790

DETAILS
AAAA             BBBB           CCCC
123421893844511  118675320014     IDLE

DATE             TIME             DDDD
150204           222245           123-42-50000-1823

EEEE
352663056076930

DETAILS
AAAA             BBBB           CCCC
```

Expected Output.txt

AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DATE,TIME,DDDD,EEEE

```
123421751116849,119865688385,IDLE,150203,161044,123-42-50300-14481,111394052866500
123421825027128,119698116932,IDLE,150204,183507,123-42-3200-10793,352708042150790
123421893844511,118675320014,IDLE,150204,222245,123-42-50000-1823,352663056076930
```

I have tried below command and in-complete

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS" "; OFS=","} { for (i=6;j=9;k=12;i<=NR;j<=NR;k<=NR;i+10;j+10;k+10) print $i,$j,$j }'  Input.txt
```

Looking for your suggestions !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use

```
awk -v RS=DETAILS -v OFS=, 'NR == 2 { print $1, $2, $3, $7, $8, $9, $13 } NR != 1 { print $4, $5, $6, $10, $11, $12, $14 }' filename
```

The trick is to split the file into records delimited by `DETAILS` rather than newlines and then pick out the appropriate fields from those records. The `NR == 2` block is only to generate the header line. `NR == 1` is the fluff before the first `DETAILS` and therefore ignored.

Comment: Thanks a lot Wintermute , It's working fine , I have accepted your answer and up-voted !!!